# Possible to upgrade react-native within Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react-native app I've developed with the latest Expo SDK, v44. That includes `"react-native": "0.64.3"`.

As react-native 0.64 still points to the sunset service jcenter, which is experiencing intermittent downtime, I'd rather use react-native 0.65. Can I upgrade the version of react-native within the current Expo version? Is it as simple as changing the version in `package.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not easy for managed workflows. [This section of Expo blog](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-dev-client-0-8-0-7116c1945253#0748) states:

> Support for React Native 0.66 in expo-dev-client does not mean React Native 0.66 is supported in the managed workflow. You will need to prebuild and upgrade your project independently to use 0.66.

So if you are using managed workflow instead of bare workflow, you'd better wait for next release. [This PR](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/15914) already upgraded RN to 0.66